# how do miners guess the next block version?

Tags: miner-configuration

ok guys, so don't laugh at me because im new into this:D

I know that each block has a different "block version" right?
but, how to guess the block version from the next block?

lets say latest block is 100 and block version is 0x1 for example.
so how can i (get/calculate/guess) the "block version" from block 101?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is Mining?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-exactly-is-mining)

Comment: no what i mean is, how to get the version of the next block...

Comment: Why do you think block version is important to your use?

Comment: Idk its because i saw every block has different version and that make me think that how do they calculate the block version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: If you are not using ASIC boost and are not signalling readiness for à soft fork, the next version number is always 20000000<sub>16</sub>

---

### Block Version Numbers

> **how do miners guess the next block version?**

They don't guess it. The version is a fixed value determined by [BIP 9](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0009) and other conventions.

The basic version number is 20000000<sub>16</sub>

Some miners use the version number in a way that speeds up mining, This is called [ASIC-boost](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=ASIC+boost) and affects part of the version number. This isn't necessary for mining but speeds up mining when ASIC hardware is used.

Part of the version number is also used for miners signalling readiness for a soft-fork.

These are some of the reasons that the version numbers in blocks can look different.

If I recall correctly, most blocks have a version of 0x20000000

```
C> cd %APPDATA%\Bitcoin\blocks
C> blockchain -file blk01000.dat -blocks
   No.|Version |Height|Date and Time   |   Txs|Target  |Id
------|--------|------|----------------|------|--------|----
     1|20000000|485510|2017-09-16 06:24|   805|1801310B|000000000000000000CC9F2D9098B4BEE4A5FD594933673735608CA460DB0BFD
     2|20000000|485463|2017-09-15 23:21|  2535|1801310B|000000000000000000B3CE55ADDFC79D01D351778FA1B8075E781EBE11EA5625
     3|20000000|485446|2017-09-15 20:39|  2207|1801310B|000000000000000000FFCC035A233732228C40208462B7ABC7FDDD4E8564234D
     4|20000000|485521|2017-09-16 07:34|  1018|1801310B|000000000000000000A3A05AC7C089630F3EF787EE328CA4BF47AFE4E6507EE1
     5|20000000|485514|2017-09-16 07:00|  1930|1801310B|000000000000000000BDB1BE6305BD0733FE2DC727D3B02BE564FF1A9949AE9D
     6|20000000|485465|2017-09-15 23:43|  2518|1801310B|00000000000000000008B7EBDB2A01DB81F07DDE6579F97A1124A4FECEC03F82
     7|20000000|485461|2017-09-15 23:13|  2412|1801310B|0000000000000000010F1A3400602B26F003840708A0579A7C0E0E2DF1594074
     8|20000000|485522|2017-09-16 07:41|  1145|1801310B|00000000000000000049D6A297B61B86C8AAE274841C8F6CF77CCE74303D8982
     9|20000000|485531|2017-09-16 09:03|  1877|1801310B|000000000000000000C938D625C41A97790F08102368B4264597D482BB066188
    10|20000000|485489|2017-09-16 03:09|  1041|1801310B|000000000000000000DF2449F82D5A027B3656A9164F4A075C58AB86AD35A38C
    11|20000000|485534|2017-09-16 09:23|   616|1801310B|0000000000000000003BFC0EF09EFB97D7C18C6A2A4D06AA309F2A090978EA0B
    12|20000012|485532|2017-09-16 09:20|  1900|1801310B|000000000000000000E279A3048C04A96F56348406674792B86B2C4E8F34CB08
    13|20000000|485468|2017-09-16 00:10|  2321|1801310B|0000000000000000010833846A46D3409C3F498690706087E6A8C696336178A5
    14|20000002|485439|2017-09-15 18:58|  2619|1801310B|000000000000000000413C4687BEFC69693FF515BC589F22F108333AD8FE312B
    15|20000000|485498|2017-09-16 04:34|  1176|1801310B|000000000000000000BA0A9DAF0EF1AD6D6D3E0282F5D9311DD188CE8292C01E
    16|20000000|485536|2017-09-16 10:05|  2207|1801310B|0000000000000000001E35BC8F4D965E49707198F5C0D749C689C8F23BE29DC4
    17|20000000|485515|2017-09-16 07:03|  1667|1801310B|000000000000000000C3BB077C2F7C3D4A70CFA5968734034D0ED71A9BF629F9
    18|20000000|485537|2017-09-16 10:15|  1964|1801310B|00000000000000000034111F28BA08203B5B816EC798632D36FCDF6B611EB2C8
    19|20000000|485516|2017-09-16 07:04|    90|1801310B|000000000000000000073090B27C16F350EF560E7488D7B02BCF8EB2405AAC2E
    20|20000000|485448|2017-09-15 20:59|  1702|1801310B|0000000000000000003F2612BC32474BBA205D99515BFCA84845428A879CD6A6
    21|20000000|485518|2017-09-16 07:09|    51|1801310B|000000000000000000BB78CA2D97D8C0B7FCC371D26E60A1D75246AE6B743541
    22|20000000|485539|2017-09-16 10:40|  2178|1801310B|000000000000000000DE2606C644FF3D32C0E93604269019C0A8E5DB5D225300
    23|20000000|485541|2017-09-16 10:45|   579|1801310B|0000000000000000002331DC210F06C878DF9E3E24C506D6DDB06A8CB213291A
    24|20000012|485545|2017-09-16 11:09|   718|1801310B|000000000000000000F650BBF8BA8853E9578E6AFB8207E72F54EA91EE3E4F8C
    25|20000000|485520|2017-09-16 07:24|   581|1801310B|0000000000000000008860EE278F8C8DBA2431DE6738B861AB9A62FA6E281F48
    26|20000000|485528|2017-09-16 08:21|    91|1801310B|000000000000000000BDA8A3E6D49E6EB2F274AE87B7BD92E29C73E857CFC5D7
    27|20000000|485486|2017-09-16 02:42|   908|1801310B|00000000000000000093EBE983E10B389170E78195E18A6851415B8F7BA8B459
    28|20000000|485503|2017-09-16 05:41|  1322|1801310B|000000000000000000159F0E9C80C635B8D2459E86976531B05592F5F1D6D86D
    29|20000000|485546|2017-09-16 11:34|  2318|1801310B|000000000000000000C6DB5773C9394BDD3BC8C03A682167DB6996FB02D88E88
    30|20000000|485554|2017-09-16 12:58|  1948|1801310B|0000000000000000001AE1E66ED842250708A7F6994DB3A84BCB67F82F1D152F
    31|20000000|485508|2017-09-16 06:03|   384|1801310B|0000000000000000006C766A6292034EE1356820020C60C6A9905ECB95A6F0D1
    32|20000000|485548|2017-09-16 11:51|  1100|1801310B|0000000000000000006CC1A446BB0A9DCB6176642A87296E24BD5EA051C50FEF
    33|20000000|485556|2017-09-16 13:08|  1140|1801310B|00000000000000000092D0E4777F8A73C7528BE3B43B4100BC3DA63A6B8BB085
    34|20000000|485560|2017-09-16 13:28|   911|1801310B|000000000000000000E13CA5B963171B100D83722BDA678B1FB831008E1027A2
    35|20000000|485488|2017-09-16 03:04|  1784|1801310B|00000000000000000023882234A2AC145F05967012EDE607649BDC2658343DE5
    36|20000000|485449|2017-09-15 21:04|  1732|1801310B|000000000000000000BAF1EDCF3566BBF9CD709B33C6D8F3F16A3B1E9999A986
    37|20000000|485535|2017-09-16 09:36|  2043|1801310B|000000000000000000D0606560B4DAA00C247DD48BC1392F80A4636C90DF9270
    38|20000000|485561|2017-09-16 13:33|   846|1801310B|0000000000000000008CA909133B5F3992ADB10EAF5D3589838721E20898A550
    39|20000000|485441|2017-09-15 19:10|  2120|1801310B|0000000000000000009794A762F1B405A76D6D3233E83505DBBBF3B5F59D2A64
    40|20000000|485552|2017-09-16 12:32|  1373|1801310B|0000000000000000007154C1830AD81FCCC892705967A39059690F94B281F6E8
    41|20000000|485569|2017-09-16 14:59|  1653|1801310B|000000000000000000F1EFBF0100E897752BB97826184D722035A1D7CCE630B6
    42|20000000|485512|2017-09-16 06:35|  1989|1801310B|0000000000000000004C8E92769A19482F7275D5A4BBFAC5FDE4F3C8E6D15D3D
    43|20000000|485565|2017-09-16 14:42|  1845|1801310B|000000000000000000416A03E23F1F58B6775130F2C0844F4D99BFDFBD2539F0
    44|20000000|485573|2017-09-16 15:08|   298|1801310B|00000000000000000004A9A86A0A7E9262BAD6C8D98692AB359C679A665ECAC1
    45|20000000|485574|2017-09-16 15:10|   369|1801310B|000000000000000000B2DFB387884735D3F609926995BF26DCBAA4A8F619B9FD
    46|20000000|485578|2017-09-16 15:24|  1075|1801310B|00000000000000000115C633FF3AFA48841C83F1C14B7907B54F037C6CDE24DB
    47|20000000|485491|2017-09-16 03:47|  1625|1801310B|00000000000000000110DD1610B3B494269D252BB50AAD05A3BCCCC390B68F64
    48|20000000|485543|2017-09-16 11:01|  2005|1801310B|0000000000000000003C9B05D1C186533E5E29E697DC8CD09BDEB1907BEC3332
    49|20000000|485450|2017-09-15 21:09|  2147|1801310B|000000000000000000405099E9A5ABC001D61538528C9E34162D27067D80DD8C
    50|20000000|485558|2017-09-16 13:16|  1485|1801310B|000000000000000000DC315A4C564D44A93FBC6D6CE67FDAD627A6A8A7D48AC2
    51|20000000|485525|2017-09-16 08:11|   471|1801310B|00000000000000000050B372B96E0F5521A64B1EB74C30774B4116B35229C987
    52|20000000|485519|2017-09-16 07:21|  1669|1801310B|0000000000000000010121FE64EF7E23E3961824369CD320DAC35F57EEF06775
    53|20000000|485526|2017-09-16 08:13|   337|1801310B|00000000000000000036F3C6C49DA015A97F3135319A238B5C7ECA6A6535B430
    54|20000000|485581|2017-09-16 15:44|  1604|1801310B|000000000000000000B46BE9E75F4758CA6A635EC5F2B90E57E1D3F2E326E4CD
    55|20000000|485584|2017-09-16 16:20|  2465|1801310B|000000000000000000F9DEC71FB25BDA22BA734AD133C24C8553FB66FEE2F98E
    56|20000000|485527|2017-09-16 08:20|  1017|1801310B|00000000000000000055243171E7AE55EB993D4ECEA98952E97228C00A7263DE
    57|20000012|485529|2017-09-16 08:28|   989|1801310B|0000000000000000006EED46D79AEB1949868BF1B35B23087BC0AB4B0EBA48F4
    58|20000000|485551|2017-09-16 12:19|  2334|1801310B|00000000000000000001ABB90BFDFB6E25A93BB1B6EE63D53362DFB0D6F98240
    59|20000000|485457|2017-09-15 22:41|  2283|1801310B|000000000000000001141FB73A048BABCAD4AB4B152ABDD25A4C8C49F0558FC3
    60|20000000|485564|2017-09-16 14:38|  1660|1801310B|00000000000000000021DD0DE04E79209048F3093D731E04D0310C6D2392757F
    61|20000000|485588|2017-09-16 17:06|  1898|1801310B|0000000000000000000F2ED2D6E2ED53DFEB257569B7FA758E757D4206A9D3B8
    62|20000000|485590|2017-09-16 17:26|  2101|1801310B|000000000000000000CA658EE8DACD5647DF56359F2A9C5980CF7BFC15321A51
    63|20000000|485533|2017-09-16 09:22|  1558|1801310B|0000000000000000007BFC78AD8B6B9C2C72D3943290A1E999970B505DE599BD
    64|20000000|485596|2017-09-16 18:15|  1418|1801310B|000000000000000000704AAEBF6BFED59125CDF09F855716612530BD03996E4C
    65|20000000|485482|2017-09-16 02:33|  2106|1801310B|000000000000000000D940BD724C72F0B4E1F4150E3BCD54780181D5F7240E1E
    66|20000000|485562|2017-09-16 13:59|  1654|1801310B|000000000000000000823AD6CD202AA4BA15D2C7D253F6B62F5D66CD84ACEC93
    67|20000000|485567|2017-09-16 14:58|  1920|1801310B|0000000000000000003F8183AC5822171EB4A3E232BAB27A1A950E92AB17494E
    68|20000000|485538|2017-09-16 10:30|  2269|1801310B|00000000000000000062559F374B34CD29B102D2736AD0270CC4634673EA101D
    69|20000000|485571|2017-09-16 15:02|   256|1801310B|000000000000000000A342DDDD5F69A68B4CC541ECA1EEE5276B9C54EB62949B
    70|20000000|485594|2017-09-16 18:01|  2313|1801310B|000000000000000000EDC496418745E8969DD26E60B47B32CBF5901B014BE649
    71|20000000|485577|2017-09-16 15:19|   782|1801310B|000000000000000000C293E81582874294A1A3B15A398DF159CEB715599CC108
    72|20000000|485602|2017-09-16 19:25|  2101|1801310B|000000000000000000714CCC9CE3A24EE7151A56256376568F132EDC3C891C06
    73|20000000|485575|2017-09-16 15:13|   721|1801310B|00000000000000000107FB256C44DB4EF1456D255882C060E982F55F4FE7387F
    74|20000000|485544|2017-09-16 11:07|  1053|1801310B|00000000000000000018820A7D0FD0A6C76050E501065F94F3143CBC5D20A04B
    75|20000000|485597|2017-09-16 18:19|   655|1801310B|00000000000000000124D39DA327F8A15ADB2AE29D682F06A81587D32228B386
    76|20000000|485582|2017-09-16 15:59|  2296|1801310B|000000000000000000EA652DEC29E534C9CE7186B72F2DE14298CB0EF705C24A
    77|20000000|485607|2017-09-16 20:02|  1251|1801310B|0000000000000000005478F10A75595B9E165146F6DBF798871671BB0B41F8F6
    78|20000000|485484|2017-09-16 02:37|  1415|1801310B|0000000000000000004FC9D1EA29137D8026E8C86E98FAF171FF5EDC89AA8029
    79|20000000|485490|2017-09-16 03:11|   301|1801310B|0000000000000000011B11607A185DEE7E9544599F46A48F77619CE58207DA8E
    80|20000000|485505|2017-09-16 05:42|    25|1801310B|000000000000000000024BA1C605637F21E25194CCB90A2DC0DC3A2DB683315D
    81|20000000|485547|2017-09-16 11:44|  2100|1801310B|0000000000000000006CB143DF2D714BC98397EAED3858FA0BCE96EA0F27866F
    82|20000000|485559|2017-09-16 13:22|  1172|1801310B|00000000000000000054528D7979436B793CE99C375E2078C4A410A59B3B9F2E
    83|20000000|485585|2017-09-16 16:28|  2054|1801310B|000000000000000000D3D1DB32807E00C318080C796C7BD9EE7633872612766F
    84|20000000|485470|2017-09-16 00:31|  2013|1801310B|00000000000000000124EAFA20500C2F5C4219DD1639A02E9CB8BBA846D14289
    85|20000000|485568|2017-09-16 14:58|  2080|1801310B|000000000000000000C8F48F73938298969D41CE9ACB4FEA8E33F70D2D7EC685
    86|20000000|485600|2017-09-16 18:58|  2027|1801310B|000000000000000000D912431A727346F2BFE56CBD67F93B839F928706CF756A
    87|20000000|485576|2017-09-16 15:15|   273|1801310B|00000000000000000081B9BB4D2887D2585232D5EF8FE5DBCB348A8A242CA33C
    88|20000000|485586|2017-09-16 16:42|  2608|1801310B|000000000000000000A728AEAAC33AD44B98664A50AA250CAB4746B492E6F853
    89|20000000|485610|2017-09-16 20:14|  1601|1801310B|0000000000000000001B997DCB64EF4A14B31EB8160F3D8064B486E5334F1CA4
    90|20000000|485614|2017-09-16 20:28|   646|1801310B|0000000000000000007AC03B9FF3A72ED78DDB1A39D39B8C5E2DD527B13389F9
    91|20000000|485553|2017-09-16 12:37|  1548|1801310B|0000000000000000008E0238B5F1D76499792E42DFB159AA7289ACA60E8EE33F
    92|20000000|485589|2017-09-16 17:16|  2130|1801310B|000000000000000001080CA54E94DAE7FA75F54CCBA31DA07CD6AA4BFFED3119
    93|20000000|485530|2017-09-16 08:53|  2137|1801310B|0000000000000000002BBC891EFACB5D420852DEEF596500FA3C86C3DF9C8FF4
    94|20000000|485587|2017-09-16 16:47|   952|1801310B|000000000000000000916FAEABBAF9B7896F6B26352BB04EA0547BAD7B06F8AC
    95|20000000|485595|2017-09-16 18:13|  2180|1801310B|000000000000000000EF266D2F022121EF28D217E150CB5F843EBA190F2DE278
    96|20000000|485608|2017-09-16 20:04|   266|1801310B|00000000000000000092D718C2DF7ECD77AFCFB0D34DCCFCD7DAD9EAEAD2BDA4
    97|20000000|485609|2017-09-16 20:04|    98|1801310B|00000000000000000036F44722FD561D12E6A2953F64E42AE805E67814A649C0
    98|20000000|485625|2017-09-16 22:34|  1362|1801310B|0000000000000000010925D512AA374A6A003858DF91950E1D040B17D00E9AA2
    99|20000000|485606|2017-09-16 19:56|  1919|1801310B|000000000000000000C3A170059A07943FE7103B92131AEB623C1C96D970964D
   100|20000000|485611|2017-09-16 20:15|   139|1801310B|000000000000000000D98025BE91F36FBD565244DB7CEF3D3CEFF233F32CB04E
   101|20000000|485540|2017-09-16 10:42|  1947|1801310B|00000000000000000079A98393201CFF364D3964DE5544D3D1562C02A770890F
   102|20000000|485563|2017-09-16 14:21|  1690|1801310B|0000000000000000012BDD07866DF758179E7DBEC7F44978407489F77383DFB5
   103|20000000|485593|2017-09-16 17:41|  1641|1801310B|000000000000000000169FA20059745894A9F8A906F45EDE01CACCE4577FF5CD
   104|20000000|485613|2017-09-16 20:23|  1469|1801310B|000000000000000000860BB1631042320C973899652B665D213DE3C34FDDC39E
   105|20000000|485598|2017-09-16 18:34|  2453|1801310B|0000000000000000005FF390BCF50B764015148DE5768A060C6944CC9E5D4622
   106|20000000|485618|2017-09-16 21:24|  2190|1801310B|000000000000000000C0C5EE1F67B08FC5994C6038870B1A6AEC89251856FF49
   107|20000000|485631|2017-09-16 23:56|  2671|1801310B|0000000000000000007E2DDB90325BE52605893750EA8F89137568E00445C1E5
   108|20000000|485472|2017-09-16 00:45|  1891|1801310B|00000000000000000009A07AA6869D63CBB472A81432BDC16E971BE1B5CCBD6B
   109|20000000|485570|2017-09-16 15:00|   381|1801310B|000000000000000000538FFE0581B504526DC3D300FFDC28F09522807C518FD4
   110|20000000|485637|2017-09-17 00:19|   784|1801310B|000000000000000000412C81EC79AA1753325DF8B754A77CE7696E8B1C0E2CFD
   111|20000000|485643|2017-09-17 00:54|    34|1801310B|0000000000000000001856FFD8A8D45AB517ABC3C5E99C1DB4C4E05FCF4CBE31
   112|20000000|485599|2017-09-16 18:42|  1905|1801310B|0000000000000000012A7227A68BB0E8EE7F1F2F3B0AF79DEC6F98ECFDCCA4F6
   113|20000000|485580|2017-09-16 15:32|   399|1801310B|0000000000000000007986FE1EE8A42015CAB76C4FC2F46DA1F507F831F135A7
   114|20000000|485615|2017-09-16 20:34|  1057|1801310B|000000000000000000E79872CC7FCF2F6A6C245694DBE2427A4C1D221EB6EC87
   115|20000000|485647|2017-09-17 01:29|   749|1801310B|000000000000000000DE07841DB68ED639920828A088A245968182D020C1D5D2
   116|20000012|485617|2017-09-16 21:21|   846|1801310B|0000000000000000011FF96DAFCBC9B68FAC2B226B99DDD5BA793FF0900EDC7A
   117|20000000|485621|2017-09-16 21:44|    28|1801310B|0000000000000000007FAE56FE43814D65D3024714D4D1D9657296F63DA76B0E
   118|20000000|485549|2017-09-16 12:12|  2027|1801310B|000000000000000000F4FD2B0281C067DECC23D0EE06CFFF173DAB4B8D2E7E6B
   119|20000000|485651|2017-09-17 02:02|   334|1801310B|0000000000000000008CC893176DA0573E5C8CAC00B1840969FD3876384385A8
   120|20000012|485557|2017-09-16 13:08|    83|1801310B|000000000000000000EA1D4A5AC28B236CC5803E6E4B5B40C91A4E7B74F5427C
   121|20000000|485605|2017-09-16 19:43|   587|1801310B|00000000000000000123B9DCFC42D4C7D82A90E52FC4882B0C71FA8804EE28B3
   122|20000000|485612|2017-09-16 20:22|    27|1801310B|00000000000000000095887DBAD03519AD559DB136AA2ED2246672D728B33209
   123|20000000|485630|2017-09-16 23:47|  2108|1801310B|0000000000000000010F3F19532B850D50A1AE9FF477C50A1D821BEFB8CC5030
   124|20000000|485656|2017-09-17 02:37|  1828|1801310B|00000000000000000096392335D314A43C983839C239BF2493BF8A2818C42B23
   125|20000000|485632|2017-09-16 23:57|    88|1801310B|00000000000000000070A6A25D0230C145CA2172E9954530CF32C7E28DC26B1C
   126|20000000|485592|2017-09-16 17:33|  1514|1801310B|00000000000000000019CFDB334196F39F2E981CF4F8B0941B40954C248D68E6
   127|20000000|485634|2017-09-17 00:06|   363|1801310B|000000000000000000D7FB8A86B7AC9BB6F900AA99BB9C0329C0ED131D7D5D68
   128|20000000|485619|2017-09-16 21:27|  2232|1801310B|000000000000000000C5BB1B0E26FAAFD2BB4EA0522591815CE922DA5611D62B
   129|20000000|485572|2017-09-16 15:06|   993|1801310B|0000000000000000003A1167BEDDE06EC9CAF32DBEB770396A264CEE1016C17A
   130|20000000|485622|2017-09-16 21:47|  2036|1801310B|0000000000000000010139AD7685E32AD82EFC322ADB2C297BD3633B59D9E847
   131|20000000|485657|2017-09-17 03:03|  2048|1801310B|000000000000000000B1D992C66572A13F4E1AA7EF2997160EFCD7A24EDBE6A7
   132|20000000|485638|2017-09-17 00:29|  1159|1801310B|000000000000000000E848EE8B4507D2E91208D58B2C654F71CA6BDD3B602987
   133|20000000|485624|2017-09-16 22:26|  2120|1801310B|000000000000000000D2DD72B63915C9C1A017D5B9100DADE141F02CB7458029
   134|20000000|485659|2017-09-17 03:09|   536|1801310B|0000000000000000002E6A2ACF672A14954C0C2BFE7EA32C0B9EBFE72FC8279A
   135|20000000|485668|2017-09-17 03:30|    80|1801310B|000000000000000000360F93AEA162D979428AD3753D225FD4EED2CCF3030360
   136|20000000|485601|2017-09-16 19:10|  2175|1801310B|0000000000000000005E7E1C2155336E2E5C0813770CD6BE3E0DD6546627EB56
   137|20000000|485629|2017-09-16 23:28|  2025|1801310B|0000000000000000005E888D617D9C7EB6C0EF84202DB56F0145238D00BE0875
   138|20000000|485636|2017-09-17 00:13|   123|1801310B|0000000000000000002C5BF7993FC154096C662B3356360242315032647902D4
   139|20000000|485635|2017-09-17 00:12|   756|1801310B|000000000000000000077A12A5419685678452D7DDD92A41F2712755C1DD8853
   140|20000000|485626|2017-09-16 22:57|  2305|1801310B|0000000000000000011A79CCD1CEFCE3BD7A26481CCF337F187E326F56840DE7
   141|20000000|485642|2017-09-17 00:51|   249|1801310B|000000000000000000AE131E814FD6F32D9DA00085FEA010174EFF31044D3495
   142|20000000|485639|2017-09-17 00:39|  1219|1801310B|000000000000000000EB7910924645841FBE9E94D08F42076D72CD7253C709D2
   143|20000000|485474|2017-09-16 00:56|  1600|1801310B|00000000000000000070BE2278935AAD781E0D3ACFCEADF2290B1E28BAC4ED79
   144|20000000|485640|2017-09-17 00:44|   602|1801310B|0000000000000000008031804A650F43CE7BA754F52A2CC093262467BD3BBA04
   145|20000012|485646|2017-09-17 01:22|   454|1801310B|00000000000000000118AE66C8F0BBD0037EF70417AD9F1AC6F1DF29041183C4
   146|20000000|485674|2017-09-17 04:30|  1781|1801310B|0000000000000000005FF909651C029DE827D9421C1EE25A3EC00FDAC58B771A
   147|20000000|485579|2017-09-16 15:31|  1157|1801310B|0000000000000000005175279D06EA252CD4A5DD4B378AC3DE188E2EFBB81B38
   148|20000000|485677|2017-09-17 04:42|   233|1801310B|000000000000000000A2D0CA5B697BD6B73F96DFAB25D32D81A8619488111321
   149|20000000|485620|2017-09-16 21:28|  1000|1801310B|000000000000000000EDF884BDA556CBE481EE22A1A9A9DCB37A3D2F1A532BD8
   150|20000000|485654|2017-09-17 02:21|   798|1801310B|000000000000000000917A0F6F4F54881F143916FC618DAFBB6D8959CAAA8585
   151|20000000|485685|2017-09-17 06:09|   768|1801310B|0000000000000000006C9382223A502089711CE36E3BAB8B72221B87C288CDFD
   152|20000000|485690|2017-09-17 06:48|   241|1801310B|000000000000000000ABDB6ABEB0ECF72D531CD12E3F00F7B51F59D584AC00A1
   153|20000000|485623|2017-09-16 21:49|   293|1801310B|000000000000000000772FA60C075C57B8BA2DB277A84454E1F8E27C3C307B10
   154|20000000|485648|2017-09-17 01:39|  1226|1801310B|000000000000000000B54E173EDE777F67C585FF7A61C3DDBB4E8C2A256DF162
   155|20000000|485645|2017-09-17 01:19|  1698|1801310B|000000000000000000FAF390A0E4AD594731B2F88C6EBDF7F15F150BDCA52A10
   156|20000000|485650|2017-09-17 01:59|   878|1801310B|00000000000000000017DF63327FC4B94DFFFD172474DCCF054F15B452F15355
   157|20000000|485660|2017-09-17 03:10|    73|1801310B|00000000000000000124F53A92043041E56A9DE0D1DB5DF4EB0318B9A6FA7E4C
   158|20000000|485653|2017-09-17 02:14|   527|1801310B|0000000000000000008C8251455416EE8C0E206A23F5CAFB2BD3506A2A416386
   159|20000000|485591|2017-09-16 17:31|  1025|1801310B|000000000000000000799DD184872066577EC76F72637ACBC95BEE603334E4BB
   160|20000000|485662|2017-09-17 03:19|    51|1801310B|000000000000000000EC1D663A6E7C4D96B60F8BA9120AB1A9EAD1671C73B703
   161|20000000|485663|2017-09-17 03:20|   259|1801310B|0000000000000000009069FFAE0ACFCA1DAF029E12F54792CA833E146F85C81A
   162|20000000|485702|2017-09-17 08:33|  1131|1801310B|000000000000000000864E9C42B3F56BCD2F5D77F2F4AA42A8A252AE7471A5E8
   163|20000012|485666|2017-09-17 03:27|   302|1801310B|000000000000000000462E69E1A49B8138CD4F1BA9348FEAC76FCB79CE502493
   164|20000000|485658|2017-09-17 03:06|  1276|1801310B|000000000000000000F24F3D98D97B380DE10B6FE403B1A4F64BE6F23E3B4A95
   165|20000000|485667|2017-09-17 03:28|   251|1801310B|0000000000000000005BADAC0910623794EE8813D63D768A4E5984A68FAC2EAC
   166|20000000|485669|2017-09-17 03:34|   554|1801310B|000000000000000000ADD5D8F44105B52B9F4E62880D82A3ECF9317960FD6C78
   167|20000000|485661|2017-09-17 03:18|  1062|1801310B|0000000000000000006D162FAD911C5CF10FCF640470EA0191499A933AA4DE73
   168|20000000|485673|2017-09-17 04:11|   536|1801310B|0000000000000000008196A4A5728BF0D813200910272421CDC9E6E80541A274
   169|20000000|485676|2017-09-17 04:40|   622|1801310B|0000000000000000007F58044FF0A8DF43BF594A623D65F4BF304C92230283A6
   170|20000000|485672|2017-09-17 04:06|  1287|1801310B|0000000000000000000922F6B37C039CC6E35B85B0191CB09CB30DC470BC092F
   171|20000000|485683|2017-09-17 05:51|   915|1801310B|000000000000000000224922D992A8F243E5CF9DB4A2C36CD1E4B35347382094
   172|20000000|485627|2017-09-16 23:21|  2048|1801310B|000000000000000000543D45CC501854D09376530A853B82F8FCC8C61E0A3697
   173|20000000|485680|2017-09-17 05:14|   784|1801310B|000000000000000001165123FC81D1A076609A1FA5F39D0E1DF35F6490287C47
   174|20000000|485703|2017-09-17 08:48|  1619|1801310B|000000000000000000EF3D2EC335888D032519405DD5BC4EEE80DE86BDBEE36A
   175|20000000|485671|2017-09-17 03:56|  1222|1801310B|0000000000000000006438C0E47EFB17A90A0AF42596C6C63C04D0CA76FF29AF
   176|20000000|485641|2017-09-17 00:49|   614|1801310B|0000000000000000002D70E46833B94438B57D91E2BFEBFCED83C3731273D76C
   177|20000000|485684|2017-09-17 06:01|   972|1801310B|00000000000000000074C4ADD9C55488F99EE2F22B6D6D93F95B73E91D1CA6CD
   178|20000000|485688|2017-09-17 06:38|  1242|1801310B|000000000000000000A5CDF3721B31978C265DCDB4335E97EE429EC21D5D55D9
   179|20000000|485711|2017-09-17 09:46|   792|1801310B|000000000000000000BA101696CE588CDFA51788B2B14186EBDB379BF8DE1175
   180|20000000|485699|2017-09-17 08:06|   101|1801310B|000000000000000000D2D2354955F438B58FD762B0D5E57ACAE62C50F898C815
   181|20000000|485687|2017-09-17 06:28|  1327|1801310B|00000000000000000122D3F1176479209378FDFAAA45E99CC3CC9C8546655CFB
   182|20000000|485689|2017-09-17 06:44|   579|1801310B|00000000000000000009BD49334F0D1DD75CF4200BA88EC7D4ADD48B88F82F47
   183|20000000|485603|2017-09-16 19:40|  1728|1801310B|000000000000000000E6795C1AD37B70D2CE4018C69E90B768B604951B027ED6
   184|20000000|485720|2017-09-17 11:00|   358|1801310B|0000000000000000003A6FD4177E95DC1C03F0AB618F4526FC302E6CF8A1B82C
   185|20000000|485478|2017-09-16 01:48|  2100|1801310B|00000000000000000015008790966FE39EEB8A6AF26DAD22D1C38DE6E65A7FFC
   186|20000012|485712|2017-09-17 09:56|  1126|1801310B|000000000000000000B34A7BED8EECBD71EF493E6F5F4DA857525E741755439D
   187|20000000|485695|2017-09-17 07:54|   962|1801310B|0000000000000000004AE4EAE283CD08334860403747BAC6E50C76E876AE9BA4
   188|20000000|485679|2017-09-17 05:07|  1854|1801310B|0000000000000000008C61E42BFA261216B5B3C2CAD176852F6FEDF5298E2489
   189|20000000|485701|2017-09-17 08:21|  1566|1801310B|00000000000000000103970E74BB991D8D68E2AA99FB36A4C3E53DB7A7468A65
   190|20000000|485713|2017-09-17 10:00|   365|1801310B|0000000000000000009BACE8C539DF0FA6B22CF0FD1FE0F6BDA8997C6FBE36FB
   191|20000000|485717|2017-09-17 10:40|   542|1801310B|000000000000000000C1EFB93FB27E2955FD761DF3FDACF769E205B3432C3EC4
   192|20000000|485707|2017-09-17 09:20|   788|1801310B|000000000000000000B13A9271D360FA6BF77EA4379B8D3167E7F44F39DDFA2C
   193|20000000|485644|2017-09-17 01:17|  1388|1801310B|00000000000000000077FE74384915351A42194696B6E222706EF10BFEAA7431
   194|20000000|485655|2017-09-17 02:22|   221|1801310B|00000000000000000076D669728589125EB23B084FB82633199709F9360AE9B4
   195|20000000|485665|2017-09-17 03:24|    94|1801310B|000000000000000000024F71745433C4F54CD2F6B5DE52FBC33F0FD47A468D5C
   196|20000000|485723|2017-09-17 11:45|  2358|1801310B|0000000000000000010280050C5C48EEEFFDC5C824C5B306D68BB34B6B9EE504
   197|20000000|485682|2017-09-17 05:44|  1172|1801310B|00000000000000000018B15A5F097E5555B6DCCC94D1F17321A857C5746AB6B9
   198|20000000|485729|2017-09-17 12:55|   883|1801310B|0000000000000000010A990E52A42756DE41415F09B5581CFF86F6831DA3E6C3
   199|20000000|485698|2017-09-17 08:05|   742|1801310B|000000000000000000AA49AC12C1D9D328BDADE8C6CBF9983B48FB9031AD71DB
   200|20000000|485616|2017-09-16 21:17|  1465|1801310B|000000000000000000C36F55B34568CD49AD81DD115A48334FC6DFFB6F88CF1C
   201|20000000|485700|2017-09-17 08:07|   108|1801310B|000000000000000001209EBB0BA6423504D68F33C2B93C050BD241E938DF63E8
   202|20000000|485716|2017-09-17 10:34|  1549|1801310B|00000000000000000097DBED6428084352D120A29C4BB5D48B7F9A1AE36A7FD6
   203|20000000|485686|2017-09-17 06:11|   336|1801310B|00000000000000000059100A0CAA94CC600D00890677D40AAE27B1DF877C5B60
   204|20000000|485633|2017-09-17 00:03|  1081|1801310B|0000000000000000011F76C46B8C2076E7AFB18F89E82CDFAF74A09570FB6D87
   205|20000000|485670|2017-09-17 03:47|  1436|1801310B|000000000000000000D65671C810A647C1982025F538287A3DB7905C0DA4ADCB
   206|20000000|485696|2017-09-17 07:58|   480|1801310B|0000000000000000008D5230FF8B1D11415C7AF949655530D6777D59BEB091B2
   207|20000000|485724|2017-09-17 12:01|  1787|1801310B|0000000000000000002089735604FF2D95C19918BDD18AC85FB97B50ABD5AF97
   208|20000000|485649|2017-09-17 01:54|  1244|1801310B|0000000000000000009B9A02A1A1045E9F4F9E6B09C6177193AB51DEA19601EA
   209|20000000|485708|2017-09-17 09:23|   379|1801310B|00000000000000000108BF4BA85BCC822110A6821AEEB78A403CE3381F621A18
   210|20000000|485730|2017-09-17 13:29|  2356|1801310B|00000000000000000053B6C0008A04B7FB3AE4CC1CA8D64DE2E4695DB479D4C9
   211|20000012|485681|2017-09-17 05:32|  1684|1801310B|0000000000000000006D171808B005A496D1BE799A6E6BDE7F3B6CEB217BF129
```

To be honest, more recent blocks are more mixed but this shows that blocks need not have unique version numbers, 20000000<sub>16</sub> is perfectly OK

I had a look at version numbers in a collection of about 650000 blocks up to April 2021:

```
Version        1 occurs 215047 times
Version 20000000 occurs 167991 times
Version        2 occurs 140752 times
Version        3 occurs 29304 times
Version        4 occurs 27212 times
Version 20000002 occurs 15833 times
Version 20400000 occurs 12413 times
Version 20C00000 occurs 10688 times
Version 20800000 occurs 10348 times
Version 3FFFE000 occurs 7605 times
Version 2000E000 occurs 5944 times
Version 3FFF0000 occurs 5547 times
Version 20000001 occurs 4976 times
Version 27FFE000 occurs 3644 times
Version 2FFFE000 occurs 3639 times
Version 37FFE000 occurs 3619 times
Version 20002000 occurs 2414 times
Version 30000000 occurs 2058 times
Version 3FFFC000 occurs 1934 times
Version 20000012 occurs 1217 times
...
```

> **I know that each block has a different "block version" right?**

That is wrong. Most blocks currently will have the same version number. Even if they differ, no guessing is involved. The number has a well defined meaning.

Each block has a unique Block-ID, perhaps this is what you are thinking of. The Block ID is a hash of the Block header. It isn't stored as a separate data item in the block data as transmitted over the network.

I wonder if you are thinking of block height? This is stored in the first few bytes of the unlocking script of the first transaction in the block - which is the miner's "coinbase" transaction.

---

For example see https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/block/765019 and open the "Technical details" section

> Version 554680320<sub>10</sub>  210fc000<sub>16</sub>
> Version [bits] 100001000011111100000000000000<sub>2</sub>

That is the version number displayed in decimal hexadecimal and binary representations. It looks like what I think of as version 2, with some ASIC-boost data embedded.

If you ignore the ASIC-boost and soft-fork readiness signalling, I think the actual version number in the "top 3 bits" is always the same in blocks mined since somewhere around 2012. Those three bits are always 001<sub>2</sub> so the first nibble (half-byte) is 0010<sub>2</sub> or 0011<sub>2</sub> which is displayed as 2 or 3 in hex.

Whether you think of 001<sub>2</sub> as "1" or "2 and sometimes 3" seems to be unspecified. It is defined as a three-bit number in the "top" end of a little-endian four-octet signed integer and these are uncommon so there probably isn't a natural informal interpretation.

Bitcoin block version numbers are pretty weird but they are not exactly the result of guessing (Though the ASIC-boost part kinda is, AFAIK,WIVF).

---

Further reading:

- [Activation of SegWit v1](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/85024/13866)

Comment: so if i use my own mining script..the block version will be 0x20000000 right?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: Alright, letss gooooo...thank you so much sirrr :D